# Extension method : how to make it work with GUID also

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, extension-methods, guid, iconvertible

i'm using this extension method for converting objects in my project. But its unable to convert `GUID` as its doesn't implements `IConvertible` Interface but for conversion i always have to use `new Guid(fooobject)` but i want that i could use this method to convert objects to `GUID`. any idea how can we make it flexible to work with `GUID` also.

Extension method is

```
 public static T ToType<T>(this object val, T alt) where T : struct, IConvertible 
    {
        try
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(T));
        }
        catch
        {
            return alt;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can always special-case checking `typeof(T)` .. although GUID does have [its own TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.guidconverter.aspx). You will likely need to convert `val` to a `string`. Otherwise, see the example on the page.

Comment: yes `TypeConverter` is not there for GUID as it's value type i guess. we need to unbox explicitly always to convert it to GUID. that's why i want to do this using Extension method...

Comment: I am pretty sure it'll still work .. if `val` is *not* a GUID value then you'll need to Convert it. If it is a GUID you can tell with a `typeof(T)` check and cast is directly.

Comment: @pst No sir, it doesn't work and shows error unable to implicitly conversion error...You can try it by making a simple example...

Comment: Oh, I see. The problem is the constraints of `T` are *too restrictive* with `IConvertible` (it has nothing to do with the stuff *in* the method). You'll need to relax them (and do the checks inside the method) or create an overload. (Although I am not sure if an method can be overloaded based on type refinement of a generic ..)

Comment: Yes it can be overloaded..i have overloaded but i just want to make it sure if it can be done with this method...Also it doesn't make sense for me to add special overloaded method only for GUID...

Comment: It isn't just GUID .. it's actually most types outside of the "primitive" values. Perhaps have `CoerceToType` (IConvertible) and `ConvertToType` (TypeConverter), as two different methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have the constraint that the type you are converting to implements the [`IConvertible` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx) (whereas the [`Guid` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx)) does not, you have no choice to create an overload, like this:

```
public static Guid ToType(this object val, Guid alt)
{
    try
    {
        // Convert here.
    }
    catch
    {
        return alt;
    }
}
```

When you pass a `Guid`, it will resolve because of [section 7.4.2 of the C# specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29) (emphasis mine):

> Once the candidate function members and the argument list have been
>   identified, the selection of the best function member is the same in
>   all cases:
>
> - **Given the set of applicable candidate function members, the best function member in that set is located.**

Given that `Guid` is a more specific match than the type parameter `T`, your second method will be called.

Note, if you removed the `IConvertible` interface constraint, you could handle this in a single method, but you'd have to be able to have logic to handle *any* structure that is passed for `T` (a [`TypeConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) instance would be handy here).